# Cannot match any routes angular

Tags: angular

I am new to angular  router, please take a look at the following code;

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: GridComponent,
    outlet: 'center'
},{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    outlet: 'center'
}];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })],     
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

app.html
--------
<header></header>
<router-outlet name="center"></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

When I hit `http://localhost:59050/#/login` I get the following error `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'` but when I hit `http://localhost:59050/#/` it shows the gridcomponent. I have also used and unused`<base href="/" >`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using auxiliary routes?

Comment: Can you try `http://localhost:59050/#/login(center:)`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `outlet: 'center'` you dont need it if you are not using auxiliary routes.

Comment: If I use is there any error from angular? are they restricting me not to name router-outlet? It is working for path1 but not for path2 so does it make difference?

Comment: i only use it for dynamic paths